How do I write a currency symbol other than $ in html document using the vs code editor
I was writing an html codes for online shopping and i needed to include a currency symbol other than the default $ option because it's going to be in another form of currency and not dollar. currency like the Naira which has N with double strike through. I can do that in the microsoft word because it has the strike through and double strike through features but i am stuck in this vs code editor
I tried adding a naira symbol but the only available feature is a dollar and euro currency sign on my keyboard

"I can do that in the microsoft word because it has the strike through and double strike through features" that's not how you should do it even in Word, though. You need to use the actual symbol, not mash up some random formatting that sort of approximates it.

First Ensure that your HTML document is encoded in UTF-8 by including this line in the head section to avoid any encoding issues:
<meta charset="UTF-8">

in you HTML use Entity Code:
<p>Price: &#8358; 1000</p>

This will render as: Price: ₦ 1000

In HTML, it is common to use unicode for currencies or other symbols. https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp
In VS code you can do this as well to print to the console; take a look at this: How to correctly display unicode characters in VS Code's Integrated Terminal?
If you want to use unicode in the file itself (in your code), a Google search will give you the answer. There are a lot of extentions for VS code to support this (and make it easy).
NOTE: Using unicodecharacters in sourcecode is not good practice!
